# Python Newspaper with web archive (wayback machine)

Tags: python, python-3.x, archive, python-newspaper, newspaper3k

I'm trying to use the Python library [newspaper](https://github.com/codelucas/newspaper) with the archives from the [Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/web/), which stores old versions of websites that were archived. Theoretically, old news articles could be queried and downloaded from these archives.

For instance, the follow code queries the archives for **CNBC** for a specific archive date.

```
import newspaper
url = 'http://web.archive.org/web/20161201123529/http://www.cnbc.com/'
paper = newspaper.build(url, memoize_articles = False )
```

Although the archived website itself contains links to actual news articles from 2016-12-01, the newspaper module does not seem to pick them up. Instead, you get urls such as:

```
https://blog.archive.org/2016/10/23/defining-web-pages-web-sites-and-web-captures/
```

which are not actual articles from this archived version of CNBC. However, newspaper works great with *today*'s version of [CNBC](http://cnbc.com).

I suppose that it gets confused because of the format of the url (which contains two `http`s).  Does anyone have any suggestions on how to extract articles from the [Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/web/) archives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an interesting problem, which I will add to my [Newspaper Usage Overview](https://github.com/johnbumgarner/newspaper3_usage_overview) document available on GitHub.

I attempted to use *newspaper.build*, but I couldn't get it to work correctly, so I used newspaper Source.

```
from time import sleep
from random import randint
from newspaper import Config
from newspaper import Source

USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'

config = Config()
config.browser_user_agent = USER_AGENT
config.request_timeout = 10

wayback_cnbc = Source(url='https://web.archive.org/web/20180301012621/https://www.cnbc.com/', config=config,
                  memoize_articles=False, language='en', number_threads=20, thread_timeout_seconds=2)

wayback_cnbc.build()
for article_extract in wayback_cnbc.articles:
   article_extract.download()
   article_extract.parse()

   print(article_extract.publish_date)
   print(article_extract.title)
   print(article_extract.url)
   print('')

   # this sleep timer is helping with some timeout issues
   # that were happening when querying
   sleep(randint(1,3))
```

The example above outputs this:

```
None
Media
https://web.archive.org/web/20180301012621/https://www.cnbc.com/media/
    
None
CNBC Video
https://web.archive.org/web/20180301012621/https://www.cnbc.com/video/

2017-11-08 00:00:00
CNBC Healthy Returns
https://web.archive.org/web/20180301012621/https://www.cnbc.com/2017/11/08/healthy-returns.html

2018-02-28 00:00:00
Markets in Asia decline as dollar steadies; Nikkei falls 307 points 
https://web.archive.org/web/20180301012621/https://www.cnbc.com/2018/02/28/asia-markets-stocks-dollar-and-china-caixin-pmi-in-focus.html

2018-02-28 00:00:00
S&P 500 rises, but on track to snap longest monthly win streak since 1959
https://web.archive.org/web/20180301012621/https://www.cnbc.com/2018/02/28/us-stocks-interest-rates-fed-markets.html
```

Hopefully, this answer helps with your use case for querying the WayBack Machine for articles.  If you have any questions please let me know.